# Django сохранение данных с формы ModelFormMixin, DetailView

Tags: python, django

Использую класс представления DetailView, который отображает всю информацию о фильме.
К тому же на отображаемой странице есть форма ReviewForm, которая позволяет оставить отзыв о фильме. Данную форму я подключил с помощью ModelFormMixin и она успешно отобразилась в шаблоне.

Проблема возникает когда я заполняю форму данными и при подтверждении меня перебрасывает на эту же страницу но пустую, форма ничего не сохраняет.
К тому же дополнительно к данным формы мне нужно добавить id фильма и нынешнюю дату.

Не совсем понимаю как в таком случае отрабатывает форма и какие методы она вызывает.

Класс представления

```
class AboutMovie(ModelFormMixin, DetailView):

    model = models.Movie

    template_name = 'movie_app/detail_movie.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'slug_movie'

    context_object_name = 'movie'

    form_class = ReviewForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        reviews = self.object.review_set.all()
        context['movie_reviews'] = reviews

        return context
```

Форма

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = models.Review
        fields = ['user_nickname', 'user_email', 'text_review']

        labels = {
            'user_nickname': 'Никнейм',
            'user_email': 'Email',
            'text_review': 'Рецензия'
        }

        widgets = {
            'user_nickname': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Иван'}),
            'user_email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'default@mail.ru'}),
            'text_review': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': '5'})
        }
```

Раньше, когда представление было в виде функции то отработка данных с формы выглядела следующим образом

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_review = ReviewForm(request.POST)
        if form_review.is_valid():
            data = form_review.save(commit=False)
            data.film = movie
            data.date_review = date_today
            data.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```

Из официальной документации не совсем понял как работает данный миксин
Буду благодарен за объяснение или за ссылку где тему можно покурить